# UNION two tables with different columns, without duplicates, and update a field on union

Tags: mysql

I want to union two tables with the structure:

Table1: Id, Name, Reference1, Position

Table2: Id, Name, Reference2, ArtNr, Price, Position

Now to the difficult part:
All fields with different "Reference" fields must be in that new table.
The "Reference" field must be unique in the new table, so there won't be two items with the same "reference".
BUT: If there's a record with the same reference in Table 1 and Table 2, the new Record must have the "Position" of Table 1. ALL Entries that are NOT in Table 1 but in Table 2, must have a new Position with the value of [MAX(Position) increment by 1] of Table 1.

I have NO IDEA, how to solve that :)
Thanks for your help!

EDIT:

To union both:

```
SELECT Id
    ,NAME
    ,Reference
    ,NULL AS ArtNr
    ,NULL AS Price
    ,Position
FROM Table1

UNION

SELECT Id
    ,NAME
    ,Reference
    ,ArtNr
    ,Price
    ,Positionfrom Rechnung_Item
FROM
Table2
```

But that shows all entries of both tables...

Sample Data:

Table1:

| Id | Name | Reference | Position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test | 123 | 5 |
| 2 | Test2 | 125 | 7 |

Table2:

| Id | Name | Reference1 | Position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test | 123 | 1 |
| 2 | Test3 | 127 | 2 |

Desired output:

| Id | Name | Reference2 | Position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test | 123 | 5 |
| 2 | Test2 | 125 | 7 |
| 3 | Test3 | 127 | 9 |

Comment: Union will work only if you have same table structure .

Comment: if you share sample data then I can try to write query

Comment: @YashveerSingh I do it with "null as Price" for example... so the same table structure is not the problem!

Comment: hi without sample data and required output query can be wrong so please share a sample to work and required result

Comment: Also you question is not clear . If you share sample data and result then it will be easy to answer

Comment: Are you sure you want a `UNION` and not a `JOIN`?

Comment: Yeah quite sure, I tried to show you what I want. I edited my question

Comment: So, you want the `Position` to be a row count?  What about the `Id`?

Comment: The id is not important here, the position is not a row count in general. Was a bit misunderstanding im my data.. it would help if the positions of table1 don't change, and the positions of records added from table2 would be (old position + max(position) of table1) - I edited the data above

Comment: @YashveerSingh I'd suggest making use of the comment's "Edit" button instead of posting back-to-back comments within seconds of each other, repeatedly.

Comment: @Inkperial please check my answer as per you input data I created th query and result ar also matching please check hope this is what you wanted :)

Comment: @Inkperial Why is the value of the `position` in your desired output `9`, and not `8`? Didn't you say the MAX position from table 1 (`7`), and increment by 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out that solution:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT Id, Name, Reference1 as Reference, Position FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT Id, Name, Reference2 as Reference, Position + (SELECT MAX(Position) FROM Table1) FROM Table2) as result GROUP BY Reference
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried creating sample data, it gives you result you required

```
    declare  @temp1 as table (Id int , Name varchar(50), Reference int, Position int)
    insert into @temp1  (Id ,Name , Reference , Position ) values (1,'A',123,5)
    insert into @temp1  (Id ,Name , Reference , Position ) values (2,'B',125,7)
    --insert into @temp1  (Id ,Name , Reference , Position ) values (1,'C','Ref3',1)

    declare  @temp2 as table (Id int , Name varchar(50), Reference int, Position int, ArtNr int )
    insert into @temp2  (Id ,Name , Reference , Position,ArtNr ) values (1,'A',123,1,1)
    insert into @temp2  (Id ,Name , Reference , Position,ArtNr ) values (1,'C',127,2,2)
    --insert into @temp2  (Id ,Name , Reference , Position,ArtNr ) values (1,'B',128,1,3)
    --insert into @temp2  (Id ,Name , Reference , Position ,ArtNr) values (1,'C','Ref5',2,4)

    select isnull(r1  ,r2) as Reference ,

    ISNULL(n1,n2) as name , newPosition as Position 

     from (

    select   t1.Reference as r1 ,t2.Reference as r2 , t1.Name  as n1 , t2.Name as  n2 ,
    case when t1.Position is not null then t1.Position else (select max(Position)+ t2.Position from @temp1)  

    end as  newPosition

     from @temp1 t1 full outer join @temp2 t2 on t1.Reference = t2.Reference
     ) as tr
```

Comment: I got this: #1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'is null',

Comment: I had to change it to "ifnull"... but now I noticed, I get an error on the FULL OUTER JOIN. Any alternative to the full outer join as it is not possible in mysql?

Comment: hi i think so you need to check . i had sql server installed and ir run fine . you need to find how to do full outer join in  mysql but the idea remains the same nd full outer is requred as you need data frm both table if uyou apply  left or  right then you will loose recods from one of the table . but i think now yoy  got the point how to achieve this

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot. I found the solution but am not able to integrate it :/ I put it into a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41752548/full-outer-join-workaround-mysql